# Issues outputting text via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/kev_daddy/pen/MMWEMG

I am building a form that is meant to update the difference between two values in real time (ie without refreshing the page). It is comprised of multiple fields, but ultimately I'll be getting the sum of two values, and displaying this using HTML.

The entire thing appears to work as intended until I get to the function that is meant to display the sum in html.

The intention is that the `result` (a hidden field) is shown as plain text in `output`. It doesn't trigger on the onset, however if i punch in an extra character using my keyboard, the event is finally heard and the text shows. up.

I am sure that I am missing something, but how do I ensure that the sum is outputted?

```
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('fee_selector_holder').value || 0;
  var y = document.getElementById('content').value || 0;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  result.value = myResult; }


var input = document.getElementById("result"); 
var output = document.getElementById("output"); input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  output.innerText = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="hostelfees" id="content" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" name="fee_id" id="fee_selector_holder" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="result" name="totalfee">

<hr>

<p>You can earn <span id="output"></span> more!
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `input` event on span. You can create a separate function and pass the value of the calculation to this function whose responsibility will be to update the `span` text content

```js
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('fee_selector_holder').value || 0;
  var y = document.getElementById('content').value || 0;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  result.value = myResult;
  updateText(myResult)
}

function updateText(val) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="hostelfees" id="content" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" name="fee_id" id="fee_selector_holder" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="result" name="totalfee">

<hr>

<p>You can earn <span id="output"></span> more!
```

Comment: Wonderful! How would you modify the snippet if I want it to rely on just a single field?